# Passing regex modifier options to RegExp object

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to create something similar to this:

```
var regexp_loc = /e/i;
```

except I want the regexp to be dependent on a string, so I tried to use new RegExp but I couldn't get what i wanted.

Basically I want the `e` in the above regexp to be a string variable but I fail with the syntax.

I tried something like this:

```
var keyword = "something";

var test_regexp = new RegExp("/" + keyword + "/i");
```

Basically I want to search for a sub string in a larger string then replace the string with some other string, case insensitive.

regards,
alexander

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You need to pass the [second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp#Parameters):

```
var r = new RegExp(keyword, "i");
```

You will also need to escape any special characters in the string to prevent regex injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks, thought I needed the opening and closing slashes. (>_<)

Comment: How do I pass multiple flags like i and g? I have been trying this since long time now. I tried "ig" but only g works. I tried "i,g" but it is invalid. I tried ["i", "g"] but it is invalid. How?

Comment: what about if you need to add ^ before the expression. This answer could use some love

Answer (score 47):

You should also remember to watch out for escape characters within a string...

For example if you wished to detect for a single number \d{1} and you did this...

```
var pattern = "\d{1}";
var re = new RegExp(pattern);

re.exec("1"); // fail! :(
```

that would fail as the initial \ is an escape character, you would need to "escape the escape", like so...

```
var pattern = "\\d{1}" // <-- spot the extra '\'
var re = new RegExp(pattern);

re.exec("1"); // success! :D
```

Comment: I was bit by the double escape when using a string to create a pattern. I am glad I found this.

Comment: One more thing that tripped me up, the string version of the pattern that gets fed to the RegExp object won't work if you start and end with "/" . A regular expression in js might be var pattern = /\d{1}/ , no quotations needed, but once you convert to string, it would become var patternString = "\\d{1}" , like Ric has it in his example.

Comment: Hours trying to get that RegExp working,and finally a awesome answer. The error was that I was forgetting \\ in the beginning, I was using only one.

Answer (score 11):

When using the RegExp constructor, you don't need the slashes like you do when using a regexp literal.  So:

```
new RegExp(keyword, "i");
```

Note that you pass in the flags in the second parameter.  See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) for more info.

Comment: haha wish I'd seen this before spending an hour pulling my hair out. Thanks James !

Answer (score 1):

Want to share an example here:

I want to replace a string like: `hi[var1][var2]` to `hi[newVar][var2]`.
and `var1` are dynamic generated in the page.

so I had to use:

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\\\["+var1+"\\\\]",'ig');
mystring.replace(regex,'[newVar]');
```

This works pretty good to me. in case anyone need this like me.
The reason I have to go with [] is var1 might be a very easy pattern itself, adding the [] would be much accurate.

Answer (score 0):

var keyword = "something";

```
var test_regexp = new RegExp(something,"i");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert **RegExp**, you actually can create a simple function to do it for you:

```
function toReg(str) {
  if(!str || typeof str !== "string") {
    return;
  }
  return new RegExp(str, "i");
}
```

and call it like:

```
toReg("something")
```