# Store regex in string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox-addon, xul

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting user input string to regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874709/converting-user-input-string-to-regular-expression)
>   [javascript new regexp from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172183/javascript-new-regexp-from-string)

I am having a little bit of a problem with regex in javascript (I'm not too used to regex in javascript just yet). I wanna replace some stuff in a string and I noticed the syntax for writing regex seems to be without `'` or `"` like this: `var replacedtitle = title.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, "");`

Now this all work as intended, but I want the user to be able to add his own regexes from the interface without changing the code (I'm doing a private project for a friend who doesn't code, and I want to be able to just send him the regexes to input when something new needs to be replaced instead of me repackaging everything every time). I did this by having a xul textbox (this is a firefox addon, but should be the same as if it was a html textbox) where he inputs the regexes, it gets added to a json object and saved. I tried doing something like this:

```
var replacedtitle = "";
for(a = 0; a < regex.data.length;a++){
    replacedtitle = title.replace(regex.data[a].regex, "");
}
```

but it wont work. I suspect it's because `regex.data[a].regex` would be taken as a string, yet replace() doesn't seem to take string as the first parameter, right?

I am a bit uncertain about this, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a RegEx object with `new` instead, and provide the pattern and modifiers with strings;

```
var re = new RegExp("\\[.*?\\]", "g");
```

Comment: oh thank you. I tried this one but I didn't know you had to remove the `/` around the regex. It works properly now, tackar :>

Comment: @raina77ow -- Thank's for the edit, I was too quick there...

Answer (score 3):

Splitting string into pattern and modifiers.

```
function getRegFromString(string){

     var a = string.split("/");
     modifiers= a.pop(); a.shift();
     pattern = a.join("/");
     return new RegExp(pattern, modifiers);
}
getRegFromString("/\[.*?\]/gim");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var string = "/\[.*?\]/g";
var regex = new RegExp(string);
```

ll work normaly.