# Building a Javascript Regex from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to return the number of times a letter appears in a word.

I'm passing the letter to a function like so

```
function getCount(letter)
{
    var pattern = '/' + letter + '/g';
    var matches = word.match(pattern);
    return matches.length;
}
```

Unfortunately matches is null so I'm unable to call length on it, I know the letter appears in the word as I've already checked that

```
word.indexOf(letter) > -1
```

I suspect the problem is with the way I'm building or evaluating `pattern`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how you build a non literal regular expression :

```
var pattern = new RegExp(letter, 'g');
```

See [the MDN on building a regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

And here's a simpler solution to count the occurrences of the letter :

```
return word.split(letter).length-1;
```

Comment: If I could give +2 for the alternative solution, I would. Sadly +1 is all I can offer.

Comment: @Kolink Unfortunately I just realized my alternate solution wasn't so good. It's less elegant now...

Comment: Or `word.split(letter).length-1`.

Comment: @MikeM This was my first answer but the problem is that it doesn't work if the letter is at start or end of the word.

Comment: It does for me! `'ergo'.split('e').length - 1;  // 1`. It's a neat solution anyhow.

Comment: I've used the `var pattern = new RegExp(letter, 'g');` solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
function hasClass(letter) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(letter,'g'); // Create a regular expression from the string
    var matches = word.match(pattern);
    return matches;
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

This was also answered here: [javascript new regexp from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172183/javascript-new-regexp-from-string)

Comment: Do you realize that this is the answer I made 10 minutes before ?

Comment: I had typed it all and was just grabbing the reference when the message came up, so I just clicked submit anyway.

Comment: sorry for not catching the dupe.