# IN Javascript, replace all after second existence of a character or replace all between two characters

Tags: javascript, string, replace

javascript, what is the best way to replace following two scenario.
    It is possible to use replace and add regex to do this, if yes, how?

```
I want to convert "aaa.bbb.ccc" TO  "aaa.bbb.*"
I want to convert "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee" TO "aaa.bbb.*.ddd.*"
```

Comment: what did you tried already?

Comment: Using index, find dot, and replace.

Comment: For those aaa bbb ccc, those characters are randomly generated. not static

Comment: Convert XXX.XXX.XXX to XXX.XXX.*

Comment: You can try splitting and joining by dot

Answer (score 0):

```js
var map = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'.split('');
var rand = function(){
    var len = map.length,
        arr = [],
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        arr.push(map[Math.floor(Math.random()*len)]);
    }
    return arr.join('');
};
var randStr = [rand(), rand()];

/* ASSUME above code is how you get random string */

var string = 'aaa.bbb.' + randStr[0] + '.ddd.' + randStr[1];

// use new RegExp() to parse string as regular expression
var regexp = new RegExp(randStr[0] + '|' + randStr[1], 'gi');

console.log(string.replace(regexp, '*'));
```

Read more about `new RegExp()` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_constructor.asp) (easy one), [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) (detailed one) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172183/javascript-new-regexp-from-string) (working example).

You should be able to apply this concept in your code now.

Comment: ccc and eee are random characters, what we sure it we have '.' between those characters

Comment: Thanks for reply, the thing is , aaa, bbb, ccc,ddd, all of them are randomly generated, the only thing which is certain is '.'

Comment: So, the question can be: to replace after second existence of '.'  and to replace between second '.' and third '.'